# Change into passive voice, "people cut trees without thinking."

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

As for me i think it must be -"trees are cut by the people without being thought."
Or maybe the being thought part is wrong, please tell if it is i am confused.

Comment: This would be a good example of a sentence that *should not* be converted to passive.  If you convert to passive, you lose the subject of the verb "thinking".  It results in bad grammar. So if the proper answer is "Use the active voice", do you still want to convert it to the passive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> People cut trees without thinking

> Trees are cut by people without thinking

The verb in this sentence is *cut* - "without thinking" is part of a phrase describing *people* but has nothing to do with the verb in the sentence.

*Thinking* is a *verbal*, but not a *verb* and wouldn't change with the actual root verb of the sentence.

Comment: We can also say "Trees are cut without thinking". In the passive voice, we can get rid of the subject altogether to make it truly passive, rather than merely shift the focus of the sentence.